# What is the difference between command grouping and pipelining?

Tags: pipe

I couldn't understand the difference between command grouping and pipelining

Comment: Command grouping as in what ? You  mean `foo ; bar`  or `{ foo; bar;}` ? Can you provide specific commands that you're confused about ?

Comment: What is the difference between ( foo ; bar ), { foo ; bar ; } and foo | bar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use () vs. {} in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606378/when-to-use-vs-in-bash) and [Difference between | and ||](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798355/difference-between-and/798357)

Answer (score 5):

The differences between these are:

```
( foo; bar; )
```

It will execute the commands in a `subshell`, so if you made any changes in the subshell they will not appear outside the `subshell`. Like

```
i=2; ( ((i++)); echo $i ); echo $i
```

You will get output:

```
3
2
```

If you do the same thing in `{ }` then it will be executed in the same environment, so the changes will matter. Like

```
i=2; { ((i++)); echo $i; }; echo $i
```

will give:

```
3
3
```

Now let's come to pipelining, pipelining is used to take input and give output to some commands.So the command:

```
a | b
```

the output of command `a` will be given as an input to command `b`.

```
echo "hi" | cat
```

will give you output `hi`.
So output of `echo "hi"` i.e. `hi` will be input of `cat` command.